# Pass parameter in pascal define

Tags: macros, pascal, freepascal, preprocessor

I'm trying to define something in pascal (freepascal).
As in c++ you can pass variable define macro like this :

```
#define REP(i,k) for(int i=0; i<k; i++)
```

How can you do it in pascal?

I have added `{$MACRO ON}` command on the first line, and as a result it can run normal define without error like `{$define lala:='hello world'}`.

But when I try `{define lala(i):=i}` the program got an error.

How can I pass variable parameter in Pascal define?

Comment: You don't want to do this. It's a terrible idea in C++. Don't copy bad ideas.

Comment: From section 1.2.48 of the Programmer's Guide: "In the {$MACRO ON} state, the compiler allows the use of C-style (although not as elaborate)
macros."  Note the "not as elaborate" part.  I don't think parameters are supported.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan tbh, macros in c and c++ are it's saving grace. sure it can be misused, but used judiciously, macros can shift complex manipulation to the compilation phase, speeding up execution, albeit with a possible increase in code size. anyhooo... there is a way to do it in freepascal - see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62401436/830899

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an **external preprocessor**, and execute it in the build system before you use the Pascal compiler on the result.

The FPC macro system is not meant for meta programming but for calling convention macros in headers and compact enable/disable logic only (like home-brewn assert and other debug logging code) and doesn't support parametrisation.

Non hygienic macros are fundamentally incompatible with the Pascal unit system, and hygienic macros are covered by inline function/procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just want to code some template in pascal like c++ hahaha. Well i will just use function and procedure then.

Comment: FPC has generics.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of macros and includes to acheive something similar to token pasting...

**ACME_Integer.inc**

```
const ACME_1 = ACME_3;
const ACME_2 = pred(1 shl ACME_1);
type  ACME_0 = 0..ACME_2;
//clear the passed in parameters so they can be reused in the next inclusion
{$undef ACME_0}{$undef ACME_1}{$undef ACME_2}{$undef ACME_3}
```

**somefile.pas**

```
{$macro on}

{$define  ACME_0:=TAllocationPatchIndex}
{$define  ACME_1:=TAllocationPatchIndex_bits}
{$define  ACME_2:=TAllocationPatchIndex_high}
{$define  ACME_3:=16}
{$Include ACME_Integer.inc} 

{$define  ACME_0:=TAllocationId}
{$define  ACME_1:=TAllocationId_bits}
{$define  ACME_2:=TAllocationId_high}
{$define  ACME_3:=28}
{$Include ACME_Integer.inc}
```

**expands out to**

```
const TAllocationPatchIndex_bits = 16;
const TAllocationPatchIndex_high = pred(1 shl TAllocationPatchIndex_bits);
type  TAllocationPatchIndex= 0..TAllocationPatchIndex_high;

const TAllocationId_bits = 28;
const TAllocationId_high = pred(1 shl TAllocationId_bits);
type  TAllocationId= 0..TAllocationId_high;
```

whilst this example uses more code than it saves, you can obviously see that the include file could be quite complex, repetitive code that needs to be customized many times.

***UPDATE - a more complex macro using named/optional arguments***

**ACME_Integer.inc**

```
     {$ifdef ACME_packed_array}
         {$undef ACME_array}
         {$define ACME_array:=ACME_packed_array}

         {$undef ACME_array_decl}
         {$define ACME_array_decl:=packed array}
     {$else}

          {$ifdef ACME_bitpacked_array}

             {$undef ACME_array}
             {$define ACME_array:=ACME_bitpacked_array}

             {$undef ACME_array_decl}
             {$define ACME_array_decl:=bitpacked array}

           {$else}
               {$undef ACME_array_decl}
               {$define ACME_array_decl:=array}
           {$endif}
     {$endif}

     {$ifndef ACME_array_type}
         {$define ACME_array_type:=byte}
     {$endif}

     {$ifdef ACME_bitconst}
        // we want to keep the X_bits constant
        const ACME_bitconst = ACME_bits; //X_bits
        {$ifdef ACME_high}
        // we want to keep the X_high constant
        const ACME_high = pred(1 shl ACME_bitconst);    //X_high
        type  ACME_type = 0..ACME_high;             //X
        {$else}
        // we don't care about keeping the X_high constant
        type  ACME_type = 0..pred(1 shl ACME_bitconst); //X
        {$endif}
    {$else}
       {$ifdef ACME_high}
          // we don't care about keeping the X_bits constant
          const ACME_high = pred(1 shl ACME_bits); //X_high
          type  ACME_type = 0..ACME_high;          //X
       {$else}
          // we don't care about keeping the X_high or X_bits constants
          type  ACME_type = 0..pred(1 shl ACME_bits); //X
       {$endif}
    {$endif}

    {$ifdef ACME_array}



      type  ACME_array = ACME_array_decl [ACME_type] of ACME_array_type;

      {$ifdef ACME_array_length}
          const ACME_array_length = sizeof(ACME_array);
      {$endif}


      {$ifdef ACME_array_pointer}
        type  ACME_array_pointer=^ACME_array;
      {$endif}

      {$undef ACME_array}
    {$endif}

{$undef ACME_type}
{$undef ACME_bitconst}
{$undef ACME_high}
{$undef ACME_bits}
{$undef ACME_packed_array}
{$undef ACME_bitpacked_array}
{$undef ACME_array}
{$undef ACME_array_pointer}
{$undef ACME_array_type}
{$undef ACME_array_decl}
{$undef ACME_array_length}
```

**somefile.pas**

```
{$macro on}

{$define  ACME_type:=TSha256IndexSliceMagic}
{$define  ACME_bitconst:=TSha256IndexSliceMagic_bits}
{$define  ACME_high:=TSha256IndexSliceMagic_high}
{$define  ACME_bits:=17}
{$Include ACME_Integer.inc}

{$define  ACME_type:=TSha256DataBufferIndex}
{$define  ACME_bitconst:=TSha256DataBufferIndex_bits}
{$define  ACME_high:=TSha256DataBufferIndex_high}
{$define  ACME_bits:=9}
{$define  ACME_packed_array:=TSha256DataBuffer}
{$define  ACME_array_pointer:=PSha256DataBuffer}
{$Include ACME_Integer.inc}
```

**expands out to**

```
const TSha256IndexSliceMagic_bits = 17;
const TSha256IndexSliceMagic_high = pred(1 shl TSha256IndexSliceMagic_bits);  
type  TSha256IndexSliceMagic= 0..TSha256IndexSliceMagic_high;


const TSha256DataBufferIndex_bits = 9;
const TSha256DataBufferIndex_high = pred(1 shl TSha256DataBufferIndex_bits);  
type  TSha256DataBufferIndex= 0..TSha256DataBufferIndex_high;
type  TSha256DataBuffer = packed array [TSha256DataBufferIndex] of byte;
type  PSha256DataBuffer = ^TSha256DataBuffer;
```